# Fortran how to write non-zero elements

Tags: fortran, stack

I am trying to debug a huge program not written by me by writing out a large selection of the variables into text files. Some are arrays and some are single values.

The arrays were declared with huge initial sizes due to the code being incomplete and people didn't want to use the allocation method as no one knew how many more things would be added to the code. As a result, if I just straight up print out the entire variable, it would also print out the millions of zeros which I don't need and make the file much larger than necessary.

I searched for a way to write out non-zero elements and another post here had answers pointing to the pack() function.

However, pack() seems to have a size limit since visual studio would not even go into the lines that actually calls pack - visual studio would enter chkstk.asm upon entering the subroutine that writes the variables and return a stack overflow error before executing any of the lines inside the subroutine (the first few lines in the subroutine are just opening file and writing non-array variables).

So, what else can I do to write out all the non-zero elements inside these huge arrays?

The beginning of the subroutine is shown below:

```
      subroutine write_everything(fileIDa,fileNamea,fileIDb,fileNameb)
          use flags
          use const
          use mphase_props_v
          use sample_props_v
          use grain_props_v
          use mphase_state_v
          use grain_state_v
          use mphase_rate_v
          use grain_rate_v
          use sample_state_v
          use sample_rate_v
          use twinning_v
          use hard_law1_v
          use back_stress_v
          use phase_transf_v
          use bc_v
          use diffract_v
          use output_v
          use YS_v
          use epsc_var

        integer, intent(in) :: fileIDa,fileIDb
        character(len=40), intent(in) :: fileNamea,fileNameb

 1      format(1h,78('*'))

        open(unit=fileIDa,file=fileNamea,status='unknown')

        write(fileIDa,'(''flags'')')
        write(fileIDa,1)
        write(fileIDa,*) ishape,irot,ipileup,kSM,iPoleFigFlag,i_diff_dir
     #    ,iDiag,kCL,iSingleCry,iTwinLaw,i_prev_proc,iDetwOpt,iDtwMfp
     #    ,ilatBS,iBackStress,iPhTr,itwinning,iOutput,itexskip,nCoatedPh
     #    ,nCoatingPh,ivarBC,inonSch

        write(fileIDa,'(''mphase_props_v'')')
        write(fileIDa,1)
        write(fileIDa,*) pack(nsm,nsm.ne.0),pack(itw,itw.ne.0)
     #    ,pack(nmodes,nmodes.ne.0),pack(nsys,nsys.ne.0)
     #    ,pack(nslmod,nslmod.ne.0),pack(nslsys,nslsys.ne.0)
     #    ,pack(ntwmod,ntwmod.ne.0),pack(ntwsys,ntwsys.ne.0)
     #    ,pack(nphngr,nphngr.ne.0),pack(icrysym,icrysym.ne.0)
     #    ,pack(ISECTW,ISECTW.ne.0),pack(ngrnph,ngrnph.ne.0)
```

Some of the array is of size 10, but some others are size 10000 and even 50 by 10000.

Note before I used pack the program writes the variables just fine, except the file is too large (780 MB) that neither Microsoft word nor notepad++ would open them and I need the compare functions from these programs so I can't just open them with regular notepad. I stopped short of splitting them into two files and decided to try to remove all the zeros.

Comment: Which compiler are you using? I might assume Intel based on your reference to Visual Studio, but it could be PGI or even Lahey. If Intel, try setting the option Fortran > Optimization > Heap Arrays to 0 and rebuild - your PACK issue may go away. Another option is to write a small routine that does the filtering for you.

Comment: You say the arrays have huge initial sizes, but are all the elements initialised? If not you can not rely on any value for the ones you do not "touch" - I say this as there may be an implicit assumption in what you write that they are zero.

Comment: @IanBush I see, you are suggesting there could also be an issue with some of the variables may not have initialized elements. Regarding that, I am sure they are at least partially initialized. Can you initialize only a portion of an array in Fortran?

Comment: @SteveLionel Setting heap arrays to 0 did solve the issue. It still goes into chkstk.asm but returns no errors. What is heap arrays about? Also, what did you mean by "filtering"? Thanks a lot!

Comment: This option tells the compiler to use dynamic allocation (the heap) rather than the stack for temporary copies of arrays. My suggestion was to write a routine that accepts the full array and prints out only the non-zero elements, then call it from where you need it. Probably more efficient than using PACK in an array write statement.

Comment: If the arrays are sparse, you could write a routine that writes out the non-zero values in a vector, indicating the position. You should ensure that the arrays are initialised to zero (or some other identifiable value) when the program starts. eg do I = 1,len(array); if (array(I) /= 0) write (lu,*) I,array(I); end do. You may also want to use the intrinsic count(array/=0).

Comment: I see. I will consider these points! Does someone want to write the answer down below so I can close up this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the suggestions from the comments, I set heap array to 0 and although visual studio still goes into chkstk.asm it no longer returns error and pack() writes out non-zero elements just fine.

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered.